# Cannot bind DataGrid ItemsSource with multibinding - simple binding works fine

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I'm facing a weird issue. I have a `DataGrid` that I want to bind to `ItemsSource` with `MultiBinding` for a reason. While using simple binding to a `DataTable` works well, I cannot get this to work with multibinding.

Simply put: the markup below works and renders the data table

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="Mock.Value" Converter="{StaticResource CollectionToDataTableConverter}"></Binding>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```

... while this does not really work - renders nothing

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CollectionToDataTableConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Mock.Value" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```

Notice that `CollectionToDataTableConverter` implements both `IValueConverter` and `IMultiValueConverter` and simply passes the value

```
public class CollectionToDataTableConverter : IMultiValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values?.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Certainly the `Mock.Value` property exists on the view model and is a simple `DataTable`. Also, debugging proves that in both cases the converter returns a proper value.

Do you have any idea what is going on with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable`, so it's not a valid value for `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. You can observe a `System.Windows.Data Error: 5` in the output window saying just that.

Second, you can easily check that the final value of `DataGrid.ItemsSource` when binding to a `DataTable` is actually a `DataView` object (precisely it's the value of `DataTable.DefaultView` property).

Now there are several ways to make a `MultiBinding` work - here's a couple:

- Return the `DataTable.DefaultView` rather than the `DataTable` itself in your converter
- Bind directly to the `DataTable.DefaultView` (use `Mock.Value.DefaultView` as binding path)
- Create a class deriving from `DataTable` and implementing `IEnumerable` (return `DefaultView.GetEnumerator()` in the `GetEnumerator` implementation), and use that class instead of `DataTable`

As for an explanation for how does it *automagically* work when not using `MultiBinding` or why it's not the case when using one - I don't know. I thought it was WPF's type conversion mechanism, but default converters neither for `DataTable` nor for `IEnumerable` are capable of performing the conversion, so I guess that's not it. Possibly the `Binding` class has some special capabilities regarding that matter that `MultiBinding` does not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, the easiest for me is to return `.DefaultView` in this case. And this apparently makes the multi binding work correctly. Thank you, really good catch!